# Providing safety in omniauth authorization with existing email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, google-plus

Ok, let's imagine I've got my Rails application and user creates account through the app with email xxx@example.com.(He doesnt have any social account). My app has included Twitter,Google+ Facebook sign up with Omniauth gem. So now, let's say, that there is a malicious hacker, which creates social account on Twitter, G+ or Facebook with email xxx@example.com. He goes to our app, he can't log in normal way, but he can easly get into account by his social account, which matches with user email xxx@example.com. So, the question is, how we can provide safety in this situation? Or is it provided mayby in the way I dont get?

Comment: Lets imagine you are new to stack overflow and want to learn how to ask a question in a way that will improve your chances of getting the answer you would need.   In that case you might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, none of the social media accounts can be created without confirming your email id. So there is no way someone is going to create account in Twitter, G+ or Facebook with your email id.